# Using two canvas elemets in the same HTML file

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

Can I use two canvas elements in the same HTML file? I need to drag images from some area and drop them in another area in the same page.

The first region is a canvas where all images are put (I will use EaselJS library for this one). the second, and biggest part, is a grid. Tell me if you have other alternatives, I need ideas to implement this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, your project is possible.**

Here's an outline:

1. Add all your images to EaselJS (as Bitmap objects);
2. Listen for mousedown events on the Bitmaps.
3. On mousedown:

   - Create an html img element (or have it available offscreen)
   - Place the img element directly over the EaselJS bitmap.
   - Make the img element draggable with jQueryUI
   - Make the second canvas a dropzone for the draggable img
   - Set the Bitmap visible property to false (so it’s no longer visible in EaselJS)
   - Trigger the mousedown event on the img element to trigger dragging the img
4. On drop: use drawImage to draw the dropped img on the second canvas.

   - Pseudo-code: secondCanvasContext.drawImage(imgElement,dropX,dropY)

Comment: I don't understand why I have to set the Bitmap visible property to false. Is it going to make the image invisible in the first area (from where I drag)?

Comment: You said "drag from" so I assumed you wanted the item to disappear from the first area.  If you want to "copy from" the first aread you can, of course, keep the first item visible. :)